# Where do database migrations sit in a Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently working on a Node.js project and I've written a number of database migrations using Sequelize, currently they're in a folder called "dao" inside the "src" folder along with my database logic. Where would migration logic typically sit in a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/migrations/#skeleton:

> All migrations are expected to be located in a folder called `migrations` at the very top of the project.

Comment: Thanks! Totally missed that